# How to separate a thin strip from the rest of data

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

I have a dataset that is represented by this picture. 
[image: data]

As you can see, there is a thin strip on top of the rest of data points. The question is how I can separate the strip from the rest, using clustering analysis or any other technique.

I have tried DBSCAN, KMeans, and Hierarchical Clustering and all gave me similar results shown by colors in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN and OPTICS are your best candidates. If the data is not too big, you can also try meanshift. But they will *not* be able to do it perfectly - some points will be "noise" to them.
It's fairly obvious that k-means and most hierarchical clustering cannot solve this.

Keep minPts *small* (5 to 10), and focus on choosing epsilon. It must be small enough to *not* cover the gap. OPTICS will be easier to use, since you only need to give an upper bound on epsilon.

Consider manually specifying a model. Tweaking parameters until you get your desired result is *not* any better. Draw a line on your plot with a ruler, turn that into a linear model by reading off the parameters...

Comment: I have tried DBSCAN like you said, but it did not work. So I drew a line and manually separated the stars. Obviously, I could not do this for a large sample for hundreds of times. What can I do then?

Comment: The sample size does not matter much for choosing a line manually. If all your data sets look like the one above (it would be interesting to see an OPTICS result!) you may want to identify the nonlinear shape to make things easier to separate and **figure out by what mathematical model to represent this data**, then how to optimize that model.